# Can I import Entities or Intents into my watson as json file instead of csv?

Tags: ibm-watson

Is there a way of importing json file into the watson instead of csv file?
I have all my data as json and would like to import it but it wont let me

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is. The closest is the V1 API to update workspaces, where you can update entities and intents with json format input, but you have to provide the rest of the workspace, and conform to the json format dictated by the API - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v1#update-workspace